# spring:bind throws error when used in a list

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a list containing users. I am trying to print it in JSP but some how I am not able to get it to print it using `spring:bind`. I get an exception. The reason I am trying to use `spring:bind` is to invole @Formatting annotation.

Code in JSP

```
<c:forEach items="${users}" var="user" varStatus="status">
   <spring:bind path="users[${status.index}].name">
      <c:out value="${status.value}" />
   </spring:bind>
</c:forEach>
```

Controller

```
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("go_some_JSP_page");
List<UserEntity> users = userManager.getAllObjects();
modelAndView.addObject("users", users);
```

BTW, UserEntity has name field. If I remove the binding and try to print the `user.name` using `<c:out value="user.name" />` it prints the value

A test sample code exists at https://github.com/hth/StatusInvoke.git

Please take a look at [landing.jsp](https://github.com/hth/StatusInvoke/blob/master/WebContent/WEB-INF/jsp/landing.jsp) line 35

Let me know if you face any problem deploying it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer to invoke @NumberFormat annotation is by using `spring:eval expression` tag

```
<spring:eval expression="user.balance" />
```

Comment: For ALL. Both the answers work in a way. I felt the empty form is an overkill. Pick which ever you prefer :)

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could get this to work is if the bean path that you are binding to is within the base command bean.  In my case I am using MyForm which has a getter and setter for users.  The spring bind tag does not seem to work outside of the base form command bean.

So your controller method needs to change to .

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView loadForm() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("landing");
    MyForm myForm = new MyForm();
    myForm.setUsers(populate());
    modelAndView.addObject("myForm", myForm);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

In your jsp have the following.

```
<form:form commandName="myForm">
    <c:forEach var="user" items="${myForm.users}" varStatus="status">
        <tr>
            <td><spring:bind path="users[${status.index}].loginName">
                    <c:out value="${status.value}" />
                </spring:bind></td>
            <td><spring:bind path="users[${status.index}].balance">
                    <c:out value="${status.value}" />
                </spring:bind></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</form:form>
```

Comment: @Mqnuel That works but not sure why this has to be in a form? Can someone explain that. Please?

Comment: Thanks for the response. It was great help.